# Proxmox + Debian: unable use the wireless network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian

can you check if my wireless setting is wrong, I have google and try all method but still cannot connect.

wpa_supplicant execution result

```
root@proxmox:~# wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp6s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
root@proxmox:~#
```

ifup execution result

```
root@proxmox:~# ifup wlp6s0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp6s0/10:4a:7d:d2:23:b9
Sending on   LPF/wlp6s0/10:4a:7d:d2:23:b9
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 1
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

network interface output

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp6s0
iface wlp6s0 inet dhcp
   wpa-essid XXXX
   wpa2-psk XXXXX
```

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 6b
       serial: 10:4a:7d:d2:23:b9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.106-1-pve firmware=17.3216344376.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:36 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

scan SSID result

```
SSID: XXXX
        Supported rates: 6.0* 9.0 12.0* 18.0 24.0* 36.0 48.0 54.0
        DS Parameter set: channel 40
        Country: CN     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
                Channels [36 - 36] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [40 - 40] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [44 - 44] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [48 - 48] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [52 - 52] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [56 - 56] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [60 - 60] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [64 - 64] @ 30 dBm
                Channels [149 - 149] @ 33 dBm
                Channels [153 - 153] @ 33 dBm
                Channels [157 - 157] @ 33 dBm
                Channels [161 - 161] @ 33 dBm
                Channels [165 - 165] @ 33 dBm
        Power constraint: 3 dB
        TPC report: TX power: 30 dBm
        RSN:     * Version: 1
                 * Group cipher: CCMP
                 * Pairwise ciphers: CCMP
                 * Authentication suites: PSK
                 * Capabilities: 16-PTKSA-RC 1-GTKSA-RC (0x000c)
```

wpa_supplicant.conf

```
oot@proxmox:~# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
# reading passphrase from stdin
network={
        ssid="XXXX"
       #psk="XXXX"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        group=CCMP
        pairwise=CCMP
        priority=10
        psk=XXXX
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `-D wext`?

Comment: Hi, output below without -D wext


`Last login: Thu Jul  8 19:16:58 2021 from 192.168.31.172
root@proxmox:~# wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp6s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Could not set interface 'p2p-dev-wlp6s0' UP
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp6s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
p2p-dev-wlp6s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
root@proxmox:~# `

Comment: I have reverted your edit. Please post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. That's Super User's dedicated tool for marking questions as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by execute 'rm /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlp6s0 '